# Inactive sessions left open by NHibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate to connect to an Oracle 11g database. The database administrator has asked me to have a look at the program as there are lots of inactive sessions being left open, and apparently this will soon crash the server.

Why is Nhibernate not closing the connections? Here is an example of the code:

```
public void Foo()
{
    using (_sessionFactory = _Configuration.BuildSessionFactory())
    using (_session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        _session.Transaction.Begin();
        //DO STUFF
        _session.Transcation.Commit();
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that disposing of the session and sessionFactory, would call session.Close() and the connection would be closed.

Is this just the connection pooling doing it's job? If so is there a way in which I can set a maximum size for the connection pool? Idealy in fluent Nhibernate?

Comment: you can change the pooling in the connection string.

Comment: @Fran ah I didn't know that, what is the syntax for that. Whay would happen if i needed 11 connections at once and the max pool size was set to 10?

Comment: see here (https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) for connection string help.  you could have 11 if all the connections in the pool are used up and the pool incremented itself by one.  increment/decrement size are available on the connection string as well as max pool size.

Comment: @Fran ah great, and this just works with Nhibernate? Sorry for the basic questions, never heard of these settings before.

Comment: It should.  Remember that under the covers nhibernate is just using an ado.net connection and these are all valid options for a connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems like your code allows creation of multiple instances of session factories, best practice is to create only one session factory.

And when you are using connection pooling, a connection pool is created for each session factory and it seems like this causes to have inactive connections.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was being caused by the use of transactions. Removing the transactions from the above code produced the following:

```
public class DoSomethingToDb(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
  using (_sessionFactory = _Configuration.BuildSessionFactory())
  using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
  {

      //Do Stuff
      session.Flush();
  }
}
```

Which seems to cause no issues.

However as suggested by @LowFlyingPelican, I have changed the creation of the session factory to occur at app start up.